# Advice - registration form 3 radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

So I have a form containing a section where users have to select if they want to enroll for a session to be held 3 times daily. The problem is, for any given session, AM, Mid-day, and PM only 5 applicants can enroll. So its a competition to get in. Here is the form section.

[image]

I am stumped as to how to determine if registration is closed for any given session. That is, if the form was populated and 4 people already registered for session **X**. At the same time some other user registered for **X** and that session is now closed. The first user may think he can still apply because his form is saying so. To disable a session the radio button has to be disabled like "**Dinner for Sunday 3rd August**" in the image below.

I was thinking to use jquery ajax to update at 10sec intervals. but that presents another issue. The response will wipe off any selections made by the user thus far. Its kind of like how amazon manages "5 items remaining". I never had to do something like this before. I am using codeigniter php framework, jquery 1.8.2.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If you only update the radio button that needs to be disabled, it should only wipe out if the user had tried to select one that was taken in the meantime. Also on a side note, you will probably want a hidden input added upon disabling so that it still gets submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the place is super-popular you might be trying to account for something that will never happen (which is OK). It may be sufficient to just show an error ("<date> is no longer available") and have them try again if there is a conflict. But, polling should also work; just disable the respective radio to not reset the whole form. Pseudo code:

```
<input type="radio" class="reservation" name="1-1-2014-morning">
<input type="radio" class="reservation" name="1-1-2014-afternoon">
<input type="radio" class="reservation" name="1-1-2014-evening">
```

--

```
var reservations = $('.reservation');
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url: 'checkdates',
    success: function(response){
        if(response){
            $(reservations).each(function(){
                if($.inArray(this.name, response.dates)){
                    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```